How Should I Structure a Product Backlog With Overlapping Features Across Platforms?
I’m a Product Owner managing a project with the following platforms:

Mobile Application

Website (responsive for desktop and mobile)

Admin Panel


Our website offers these features:
Home Page: Banner, Stories Section, Filters (e.g., Rent/Buy, Categories like Land, Apartments), Land Block Listing Cards.
Listing Details Page: Gallery, Description, Agent Info, Facilities, Interactive Map, Reservation Flow.
Other Features: Notifications, advanced filters, and responsive behaviors for the website.
We also support three user types: Guest, Member, and Agent.

Is it better to structure the backlog with platform-based epics (e.g., Mobile, Web, Admin Panel) or business-focused epics (e.g., Listings, Reservations, Search)?

How should I handle overlapping features, like “Listing Cards,” used across multiple platforms?

Where should platform-specific behaviors, like mobile-specific features or responsive views, be documented to avoid redundancy?



I see a backlog as a tool for promoting visibility into what the team is working on now and what it will likely be working on soon. Understanding the specific stakeholders and their needs can help inform the best choices. Your tools can also inform how you structure your backlog to support your stakeholders.
My preference would be a business-focused approach but maintaining the ability to track work by platform.
In Jira, for example, I would create one product per platform. This would result in at least three projects - the Mobile Application, the Website, and the Admin Panel. I'd also consider an overall project for the system as a whole. By having a project for the overall product or system, you can represent features and give stakeholders visibility into the work progress. However, these issues would be linked to work in each of the other projects that may be impacted, which lets the development teams have more focused views for planning and execution. This structure would support the use of capabilities like Jira Advanced Roadmaps. The issues within each platform's project would use the version and component fields to connect the work with releases, deployments, and logical system components.
You can take a very similar approach with GitHub Issues, where each repository would have Issues related to that part of the system. However, you can create a Project that incorporates issues from multiple repositories to give a higher-level overview.

Epics should be feature based, not platform based. Jira has a nice solution for this kind of labeling, which is "Component". You create an epic for "Listings" for example, then you create your stories and you can set your "Component" as "Mobile App", "Web App", etc.
Every story should be platform specific to handle the related tasks and do & track the test accordingly.
For documentation, you can use Confluence and link them in your issues if you're using Jira. For other platforms, there are also solutions like commenting or linking documentation to the tasks, etc.
